# Integration between TrustKit and AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-3, certificate-pinning

is it possible integrate TrustKit (https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit) with AFNetworking? Any suggestion for IOS?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
[manager setSessionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge * _Nonnull challenge, NSURLCredential *__autoreleasing  _Nullable * _Nullable credential) {
    __block NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition dispositionToReturn = NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;
    if (![TrustKit.sharedInstance.pinningValidator handleChallenge:challenge completionHandler:^(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable credential) {
        dispositionToReturn = disposition;
    }]){
        return NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;
    }
    return dispositionToReturn;
}];
```